# When would you create an Object from an inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm currently looking into inheritance and polymorphism and I'm a bit confused about where you'd want to create a Person object of type Student?
assuming the following code:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public int YearOfStudy { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string PredictedGrade { get; set; }
}
```

Now looking online, there are a few options here in terms of creating an object:

```
Person p = new Person();
Student s = new Student();
Person ps = new Student();
```

The first objects allows me to set name, age and gender, while the second allows me to set those 3, as well as yearsOfStudy, course and predictedGrade. But I'm unsure of what the third object allows me to do? I can still set all 6 parameters, however I can only use the attributes set in the Person class? Any explanation on the correct usage of the third object would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the confusing part?  If you create a new `Student()` you can populate the 3 properties of `Student`, and the 3 properties of `Person`.  However you wont be able to access both sets of properties unless your variable is of type `Student`

Comment: The power is when you create a new Teacher type. How would you perform the same operation on each person in a classroom? Cast them all to Person and iterate the collection, performing the same action on them (DuckAndCover()?)

Comment: Think about when you have a method to verify age. Your verify method would take in a `Person` because that's all that's needed. It works for `Person` and `Student` and anything else that make be of `Person`.

Comment: @Will that method name, too soon... haha

Comment: I think the question is more *why would I declare a instance of an inherited type as its base type*

Comment: I know this is only an example, but do not store computed values like `Age` since it changes without notification, instead store `Birthdate` and compute age from that when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of this as `Person ps = new Student()` yet.

The real benefit is being able to abstract common code for all types of `Person`. So your methods may take in a `Person` because that's all it needs and will work with any person type you create such as `Janitor`, `Teacher`, etc.

```
var myStudent = new Student()

VerifyAge(myStudent);
VerifyYearOfStudy(myStudent);

public bool VerifyAge(Person person)
{
    return person.Age < 200;
}

public bool VerifyYearOfStudy(Student student)
{
    return student.YearOfStudy <= DateTime.Now.Year;
}
```

To clear up some confusion the only time you ever really declare the base in a method is when you want to actually denote that this variable is only meant to be used as that specific type. Think of it as if you had declared your variable using an interface instead. Sure I am working with a `Student` instance, but I am only working with it as a `Person` instance or as `IPerson`.

Normally as a variable in a method you wouldn't do that because pretty much the defacto standard is to just use `var` for everything nowadays. Where you do make the choice to define `Person` is normally on properties, method return values, and method parameters. Local variable is not really important.

Comment: beat me to it, I had almost the exact same answer.. (Teacher & Janitor)

Comment: @KyleB Sorry lol. If your answer is better though then please post it!  xD

Comment: but isn't ops question why you would ever use `Person ps = New Student();` in which case `VerifyYearOfStudy()` wouldn't work.

Comment: @CharlesMay I thought that came from the confusion due to it just being possible to do it. That's why I showed it as an argument instead to illustrate. Other than a factory class, I don't know why anyone would really write that line unless it's a local method and you were only using the base properties.

Comment: Thanks for the replies there. My understanding is that I'd always either use `Student s = new Student();` or `var student = new Student();` for creating a new student (or any other classes that could inherit from Person, such as 'Teacher'), but I've seen the third option used in examples, so I just wanted to check if there was ever a situation where it was useful or not, since I'm limited to just getting 'Person' data

Answer (score 1):

Because `Student` class is derived from `Person` class, any `Student` object is also a `Person` object. Thus a notation `Person ps = new Student();` means we're declaring variable `ps` to be of type `Person` and instantiate it as `Student`. It could be used if you have a method that takes `Person` object as parameter, e.g.

```
 public void Foo(Person p) { if(p.Age > 21) Console.WriteLine("OK to drink!"); }
```

However, if you have a method that operates on properties of derived class you must declare and instantiate the instance of it. So for

`public void Foo(Student s) {if(s.YearOfStudy == 1) Console.WriteLine("Freshman");` }

you must use `Student s = new Student();`.